Get client content from minimized window - Awesome WM
I am attempting to make a pop-up that displays window previews as a tasklist and have almost gotten it, but for a couple of things.
I first added a tasklist that used a clienticon widget to group classes and added a button trigger to launch the pop-up widget. Here is my tasklist code:
function theme.at_screen_connect(s)
    
    ...
    
    -- Create an icon only tasklist widget
    s.mytasklist = awful.widget.tasklist {
       screen   = s,
       filter   = awful.widget.tasklist.filter.currenttags,
       source = function()
           -- Get all clients
           local cls = client.get()
    
           -- Filter by an existing filter function and allowing only one client per class
           local result = {}
           local class_seen = {}
           local class_num = 0
           local class_index = {}
           for _, c in pairs(cls) do
               if awful.widget.tasklist.filter.currenttags(c, s) then
                   if not class_seen[c.class] then
                       class_seen[c.class] = true
                       class_index[c.class] = class_num
                       class_num = class_num + 1
                       table.insert(result, c)
                   end
               end
           end
           return result
       end,
       -- buttons  = awful.util.tasklist_buttons,
       --buttons  = awful.button({ }, 1, tasklistButton(c)),
       buttons  = awful.button({ }, 1, function (c)
               
               local client_num=0
               
               for i, cl in pairs(client.get()) do
                  if cl.class == c.class then
                      if cl.screen == c.screen then
                          client_num = client_num + 1
                      end
                 end
               end
               
               if client_num > 1 then
                   
                   if cl_menu then
                       if cl_menu_class == c.class then
                           cl_menu.visible = false
                           cl_menu=nil
                       else
                           
                           cl_menu.visible = false
                           cl_menu=nil
                           
                           cl_menu_class = c.class
                           cl_menu=clientClassPopup(c)
                           cl_menu.visible=true
                       
                       end
                       
                   else
                       cl_menu_class = c.class
                       cl_menu=clientClassPopup(c)
                       cl_menu.visible=true
                   end
               
               else
                   
                   if cl_menu then
                       cl_menu.visible = false
                       cl_menu = nil
                   end
                   
                   if client.focus == c then
                       c.minimized = true
                   
                   else
                       client.focus = c
                       awful.tag.viewonly(c:tags()[1])
                       c:raise()
                   end
               end
           
           end),
       layout   = {
           spacing_widget = {
               {
                   forced_width  = 24,
                   forced_height = 1,
                   thickness     = 1,
                   color         = '#BBBBBB',
                   widget        = wibox.widget.separator
               },
               valign = 'center',
               halign = 'center',
               widget = wibox.container.place,
           },
           spacing = 2,
           layout  = wibox.layout.fixed.vertical
       },
       -- Notice that there is *NO* wibox.wibox prefix, it is a template,
       -- not a widget instance.
       widget_template = {
           {
               wibox.widget.base.make_widget(),
               forced_width  = 1,
               id            = 'background_role',
               widget        = wibox.container.background,
           },
           {
               {
                   id     = 'clienticon',
                   widget = awful.widget.clienticon,
               },
               margins = 4,
               widget  = wibox.container.margin
           },
           nil,
           create_callback = function(self, c, index, objects) --luacheck: no unused args
               self:get_children_by_id('clienticon')[1].client = c
           end,
           layout = wibox.layout.align.horizontal,
       },
    }
    
    ...
    
    -- Create the wibox
    -- s.mywibox_left = awful.wibar({ position = "left", screen = s, width = dpi(36), bg = gears.color.create_linear_pattern("linear:0,0:0,5:0,#ff0000:1,#0000ff"), fg = theme.fg_normal })
    s.mywibox_left = awful.wibar({ position = "left", screen = s, width = dpi(48), bg = theme.bg_normal, fg = theme.fg_normal })

    -- Add widgets to the wibox
    s.mywibox_left:setup {
        layout = wibox.layout.align.vertical,
        small_spr,
        s.mytasklist,
    }
    
    ...
    
end

From the code you can see that clicking on the tasklist class item triggers a function that handles the pop-up menu. Here is the function code:
function clientClassPopup(c)
    
    client_class_grid = wibox.widget {
        expand = false,
        forced_num_cols = 1,
        spacing = 1,
        vertical_spacing = 1,
        layout = wibox.layout.grid,
    }
    
    client_class_popup = awful.popup({
        screen       = c.screen,
        widget       = client_class_grid,
        shape        = gears.shape.rounded_rect,
        border_width = 1,
        border_color = theme.fg_focus,
        ontop        = true,
        visible      = false,
           
    })
    
    client_class_popup:connect_signal('mouse::leave', function(self)
        self.visible = false
    end)
    
    class_count = 0
    
    client_index = 0
    
    class_seen = {}
    
    class_index = {}
    
    for i, cl in pairs(client.get()) do
        
       if not class_seen[cl.class] then
           class_seen[cl.class] = true
           class_index[cl.class] = class_count
           class_count = class_count + 1
       end
        
        if cl.class == c.class then
            if cl.screen == c.screen then
                
                size = 256
                
                local surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.Format.RGB24,20,20)
                local cr = cairo.Context(surface)
                
                local s, geo = gears.surface(cl.content), cl:geometry()
                local scale = math.min(size/geo.width, size/geo.height)
                local w, h = geo.width*scale, geo.height*scale
                local dx, dy = (size-w)/2, (size-h)/2
                
                client_tasklist_item = wibox.widget.imagebox()
                
                client_tasklist_item.fit = function(context, width, height) 
                    return 100, 100
                end
                
                client_tasklist_item.fit = function(self, context, width, height)
                    local size = math.min(width, height)
                    return size, size
                end
                
                client_tasklist_item.set_client = function(self, cl)
                    ret._private.client[1] = cl
                    self:emit_signal("widget::redraw_needed")
                end
            
                client_tasklist_item.draw = function(self, content, cr, width, height)
                    --cr:translate(dx, dy)
                    gears.shape.rounded_rect(cr, w, h, 10)
                    cr:clip()
                    cr:scale(scale, scale)
                    cr:set_source_surface(s)
                    cr:paint()
                end
                client_tasklist_item.new = function(cl)
                    local ret = wibox.widget.base.make_widget(nil, nil, {
                        enable_properties = true,
                    })
                
                    rawset(ret, "fit"       , fit       )
                    rawset(ret, "draw"      , draw      )
                    rawset(ret, "set_client", set_client)
                    ret._private.client = setmetatable({cl}, {__mode="v"})
                    return ret
                end
                
                client_tasklist_item.forced_width = w
                client_tasklist_item.forced_height = h
                
                client_tasklist_item:buttons(my_table.join(
                    awful.button({}, 1, function ()
                            if client.focus == cl then
                                cl.minimized=true
                                client_class_popup.visible=false
                            else
                                client.focus = cl
                                cl:raise()
                                client_class_popup.visible=false
                            end
                        end)
                    )
                )
                
                bg_client_tasklist_item = wibox.widget{
                    client_tasklist_item,
                    bg = theme.bg_normal,
                    resize = true,
                    shape = gears.shape.rounded_rect,
                    widget = wibox.container.background
                }
                
                client_class_grid:add(bg_client_tasklist_item)
                
                client_index = client_index + 1
            end
        end
    
    end
    
    return client_class_popup
end

The function launches a pop-up with a grid layout and then iterates through clients on the screen and adds an imagebox widget painted with a cairo surface of the client window contents and adds button and hover behaviour My issue comes from minimized clients. When a client is minimized the contents aren't drawable and the box is blank.
I have tried numerous things to fix this including trying multiple different compositors for Awesome WM. I am running Arch Linux if that helps. In particular I am curious if there is something I am missing in creating the tasklist that would allow me to get the client contents even when minimized when utilizing a compositor.
Any and all help much appreciated and apologies for the hacky code. LUA and cairo are not my expertise.
Thank you.
-Robert

This is mostly an X11 question and not AwesomeWM specific. The problem is basically, that X11 comes from a time when memory was really precious and so only the actual screen contents are saved in memory. Try having a floating window above another window. I would expect that c.content would also show the content from the floating window. This also means that minimised windows are explicitly told that they are not visible and don't have to draw their content. Thus, there is nothing you can get this content from. Sorry.

I've thought of a work around, but am unsure why it isn't working. In the above code, just before the content is grabbed, I unminimize the client, grab the content, and then reminimize the client. When I do this, I expected the content to be grabbable, but it is still blank. How can I force cl.content to update?

Sounds like a timing issue (race condition). When you unminimize the client, AwesomeWM will not do it immediately, but only at the end of the current main loop iteration. At that point, it will tell the X11 server "please make this window visible". The X11 server will do that and tell the program "your window became visible; please draw its content". The program will draw its content. The window manager doesn't get any information when drawing is done. It only places windows.

So do answer your question on how to make .content update: Wait 0.01 seconds between unminimising the client and grabbing the screenshot (= start a timer). Oh and of course: Hope that 0.01 seconds is enough. It will sometimes fail because that time was not long enough.
